# shorthand for Experiment 1 and Experiment 2

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is a proper shorthand for "Experiment 1 and Experiment 2"

(1) Experiments 1 and 2

(2) Experiment 1 and 2

(3) none of the above

?

If (3), please let me know what it should be. The context is that there are two experiments in a project. Experiment 1 tested ABC, and Experiment 2 tested DEF, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

> Experiments 1 and 2

As experiments are plural

> Experiments: more than one (kind of) experiment